# Port a Ruby on Rails blog to Wordpress

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wordpress, post, import

I have a Ruby on rails blog made by someone else that is no longer involved. I want to port it to a new Wordpress blog. Textface.com is the RoR blog.

I have the Wordpress self hosted site up and running. Txtinganddriving.com

Before I change domains I need to have all the post ported from RoR blog to Wordpress.
I do not know RoR very well so I am unsure how to go about it.

I already tried porting RSS Feed and it dosnt inlcude the images since this is a Photoblog. Also it only go so far back and I want the whole site ported.

I would like to include Post title, date posted, and Image.

Thanks for your input!!

Comment: Is this RoR blog's CMS system built from scratch, or using a framework?

Comment: I am really not sure but I am going to say from scratch cause its so crappy. LOL

Comment: I wish there was away to know....

Answer (score 1):

Do you want a 1:1 copy of the site, or just the posts title, content and post date?

If you have access to the database, just write some PHP code to insert the appropriate objects into your MySQL database.

If not, write a simple HTML scraper and scrape whatever you need.

Comment: 1:1 would be nice but was settling for at least those things.

Comment: I am only used to doing everything in Wordpress itself, not PHP but willing to do whatever it takes to port the site. I am unsure how to get to the Heroku DB even tho I have access to it. ROR and Heroku are new to me. 
HTML scraper is new to me too lol

Comment: When I scrap the old site how to I import it into Wordpress?